# Jenkinsfile conditionally running stage when environment variable is a certain value

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to use an environment variable in a when condition. I only want to run a stage if the env var job name is a certain value. My when clause below is failing.

```
pipeline{
   environment {
     JOB_BASE_NAME = "${env.JOB_BASE_NAME}"
   }
   
  stage('Run conditional stage based on job name'){
     when {
        expression{    
            ${JOB_BASE_NAME} === "My Job Name" 
        }
     }
    steps{
         // some job steps
     }
  }
}
```

On the `expression` line - I'm getting an `Unsupported operation in this context` error on the dollar sign character.

How can I fix this when condition?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Edited the error in above

Comment: @Ryan it is failing because you are trying to use string interpolation outside a string - Just use `expression { JOB_BASE_NAME == 'My Job Name' }`

Comment: @Ryan Btw, why are you running `JOB_BASE_NAME = "${env.JOB_BASE_NAME}"` in the env block it is exactly like writing: `env.JOB_BASE_NAME = env.JOB_BASE_NAME` and it has no meaning.

Comment: Try changing to

`when{ JOB_BASE_NAME = "My Job Name"  }`
without `expression`

Comment: Thank you `expression { JOB_BASE_NAME == 'My Job Name' }`  worked!

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to do this:

```
when {
  expression { JOB_BASE_NAME == 'My Job Name' }
}
```